# SharePoint 2019 on premise - Open lookup column item without modal

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, json-formatting

Does anyone know any JSON formatting which will open a lookup field item directly without opening in a modal first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formate the lookup field as following(remember to change the source list for yourself):

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField.lookupValue",
   "attributes": {
      "href": {
         "operator": "+",
         "operands": [
            "http://sp2019:711/Lists/Strategies/DispForm.aspx?ID=",
            "@currentField.lookupId"
         ]
      },
      "target": "_blank"
   }
}
```

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Comment: Thanks Julie - I will try this one out.